# Gulp autoprefixer is not prefixing

Tags: javascript, gulp, autoprefixer

I am not sure why but Autoprefixer is not adding any prefixes to the compiled CSS. Does anyone know?

Here is my gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

exports.default = () => (
    gulp.src('css/styles.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

---

gulp- v
CLI version: 2.2.1
Local version: 4.0.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does!

```
input::placeholder { color: red; }
```

results in

```
input::-moz-placeholder {
        color: red;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: red;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: red;
}
input::placeholder {
        color: red;
}
```

You've probably used css rules that don't need prefixes with your current configuration. Check [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries) for custom prefixing rules

Comment: Thanks @Sharak

you are right, it does work with :: placholder selector

Not sure why it does not add any prefixes to my css that uses flexbox


.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-content:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

Comment: Probably because browsers that need prefixes for this, aren't used enough anymore. That's expected. If you still want prefixes for IE for example, then add it specifically in `browserslist`.

Comment: Thanks, Sharak, this is very helpful. I wish I could upvote your answer :)

Comment: You can always mark it as the solution to your question 